# What is the best way to track teleport position in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am using the [aframe-teleport-controls](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls) and I was wondering what is the best way to track the position of the user.

I've been searching and I found two ways to do that.

1 - I use the position of the teleport controller which is almost the position of the user.

```
var teleportControls = el.closest('a-scene').querySelector('[teleport-controls]');
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(teleportControls.object3D.matrixWorld);
console.log(worldPos);
```

2 - I define an a-camera element in my scene and I use his position.

```
var teleportControls = el.closest('a-scene').querySelector('a-camera');
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(teleportControls.object3D.matrixWorld);
console.log(worldPos);
```

I'm not sure it is the good practice, and how can I listen that the user change his position?

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller element (not the camera) will emit a `teleport` event when the user teleports (found in [source here](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls/blob/4ad9244a1a9ca8d13ab6b57ae6c6270345bca101/index.js#L250-L254)). The easiest way to detect those events would be to listen on the scene element, as the events bubble up.

```
sceneEl.addEventListener('teleport', function (e) {
  console.log(e.detail.oldPosition, e.detail.newPosition);
});
```